# PHP Post in URL without using GET

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I'm currently working on some code. Where you should be able to upload a file and select witch type of file it is.

I'm using urls to make an database entry on the upload page , so my link should look like

```
www.mydomain.domain?id=1&type=type
```

But php only gets the id because it uses get from the previous page.

So it looks like this

```
www.mydomain.domain?id=1&type=
```

So my question is how can I get the selection in the url?

I tried it with jQuery but I suck at it ;D.

My form code:

```
<?php
$datetype = $_POST['dateiart'];
echo $datetype;
$ek = $_GET['id'];
?>

<form action="upload.php?id=<?php echo $ek; ?>&type=<?php echo $datetype;?>"  target="_blank" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dateiauswahl">
    Datei zum hochladen auswählen
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"> <br>
    <input onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Datei hochladen" name="submit"><br><br>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ek?>" id="id" name="submit"><br><br>

      <label>Dateiart:
    <select  name="dateiart" form="dateiauswahl" size="5">
      <option value="EK-Rechnung">EK-Rechnung</option>
      <option value="Kaufvertrag">Kaufvertrag</option>
      <option value="VK-Rechnung">VK-Rechnung</option>
      <option value="Datenblatt">Datenblatt</option>
      <option value="Sonstige">Sonstige</option>
    </select>
  </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', '', '');
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ek = $_GET['id'];
$dateiart = $_GET['type'];
echo $dateiart;
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "pdf"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }


        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Dateien (Link, EKNR, Datei_Bezeichnung) VALUES (:Link, :EKNR, :Datei_Bezeichnung)");
        $result = $statement->execute(array('Link' => $target_file, 'EKNR' => $ek, 'Datei_Bezeichnung' => $dateiart));

}
?>
```

Comment: You have the field already in the form, why do you try to put it again into the url (which is not possible)? Read the datetype from the POST data in the upload.php!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass parameters as hidden inputs instead of printing them in the query string of action URL of the form. Use `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent security issues.

```
<?php 
 if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !isset($_GET['type'])){
     die('Missing parameters');
 }
?>


<form action="upload.php"  target="_blank" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dateiauswahl">
    Datei zum hochladen auswählen

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']) ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['type']) ?>">


    ....... other inputs

</form>
```

The in the upload.php script get them from `$_POST` superglobal.

```
$ek = $_POST['id'];
$dateiart = $_POST['type'];
```